# Save high score at other view controller

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I click on a button, and get the points, I click at another button and the game is over. The score is saved. But Now I want to make it possible to get a high score. How is it possible to get the high score seen on the second view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Let your first view controller be `ViewController` and the second one be `ViewController_2`. And let there be a array called `scores` in `ViewController` that you set when the `button` is clicked. Now, you need another variable in `ViewController_2` of type Int, let it be `score_2`, which score's HighScore.

Here's how ViewController_2 should look like:

```
class ViewController_2: UIViewController {
      var score_2:Int;
      override func viewWillAppear(){
        //ScoreLabel.text="High Score : \(score_2)"
      }
    }
```

Here's how ViewController should look like :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var scores:[Int];

  @IBAction func foo(sender:Button) {
    let score:Int=getScore()
    scores.append(score)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destination=segue.destinationViewController as ViewController_2
    destination.score_2=maxElement(self.scores)
 }
}
```

Read about [segues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2), It will surely help you.

Comment: I dint write the code yet, but I can't find in the code about the high score. Saving the score in the app do I already have.

Comment: Can you send the code in a Xcode project :) ? I don't get it (I'm a starter).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to save a highscore is through `NSUserDefaults`. This will allow you to save something such as a highscore and then call for it anytime within your app.

```
let highscore = label.text;
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey: "Highscore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

In this case I have whatever is in the label is then saved as your new highscore. You will want to implement a way to make sure that this score has to be higher then your previous highscore in order to be saved.

if you want to call it to another view controller all you have to do is:

```
        NewLabel.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Highscore")
```

I hope this helps

Comment: The label at the first view controller is also connected with the score label in the second view controller, does that effect the code? Because it gives only errors. let highscore = label.text gives the error: view controller type does not have a member named score. (the label where the score stands). NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey: "Highscore") gives the error expected declaration.  And where needs NewLabel.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Highscore") stand, the first or second view controller?